# How to remove / just from a specific line?

Tags: text-processing

I've a file as below

```
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john/1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john/1'|'te/xt'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary/2'|'text'
'DEF'|filler|'N'|'jane/3'|'text'
```

after the initial grep,

```
$ wordY="'Y'|"
$ wordN="'N'|"
$ grep ABC test.txt | grep "$wordY\|$wordN'[[:alpha:]]+/"
```

which is returning

```
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john/1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john/1'|'te/xt'    
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary/2'|'text'
```

I now wish to remove the `/` for the names only and save it to a new .txt file

so my ideal output would be

```
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'te/xt'    -- / should not be removed for 'te/xt'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary2'|'text'
```

how do I add on to the command to get the output?

Comment: Hi, it's not clear in your first example starting `grep ABC test.txt` whether the code  after the pipe is doing anything. I get three lines returned with just `grep ABC test.txt` alone. Do you need to add an example line where (let's say) the third column contains a non-`'Y'` or non-`'N'` character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input is a "simple" CSV file using `|` as the field delimiter and without fields with embedded delimiters or newlines, we may use `awk` to address the specific field we want to modify.

```bash
$ awk -F '|' -v sq="'" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $1 == sq "ABC" sq { gsub("/","",$4); print } ' file
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'te/xt'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary2'|'text'
```

With `-F '|'` we make `awk` read the input as newline-separated records of `|`-delimited fields.  Since handling single quotes in in-line `awk` scripts can be tricky and result in unreadable code, we also set the `awk` variable `sq` to a single quote character.

The code detects any record whose 1st field's value is precisely `'ABC'`, and for these records, it removes all slashes from the 4th field before outputting the (possibly) modified record.

We could also avoid hard-coding any of the 1st field data and instead just pass the whole string we want to detect into a variable (here, `query`):

```bash
$ awk -F '|' -v query="'ABC'" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $1 == query { gsub("/","",$4); print } ' file
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'te/xt'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary2'|'text'
```

---

As pointed out in the comments below (now deleted), you may *possibly* want to output the modified records only if they actually contained a slash in the 4th column.  This may *simplify* our command somewhat:

```bash
awk -F '|' -v query="'ABC'" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $1 == query && gsub("/","",$4)' file
```

The `gsub()` command returns the number of substitutions it has made, which means it will return the number of slashes present in the original 4th field.  If there were none, the function returns zero, which will cause the record to *not* be printed.

Would you also want to ensure that the 3rd field is either `'Y'` or `'N'`, you may do that with

```bash
awk -F '|' -v query="'ABC'" -v yn="^'[YN]'$" '
    BEGIN { OFS = FS }
    $1 == query && $3 ~ yn && gsub("/","",$4)' file
```

Here, we're passing in a regular expression that our 3rd field needs to match into the `awk` variable `yn`, then using that in `$3 ~ yn` to perform our test. The expression `^'[YN]'$` matches either `'Y'` or `'N'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En "\~^('ABC[^YN]*(Y|N)'\|'[[:alpha:]]+)/~s//\1/p" input_file
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'te/xt'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary2'|'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```bash
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"; q="\047"} 
       ($1==q"ABC"q)&&($3~q"Y|N"q)&&($4~"/") { sub("/","",$4);print }
      ' test.txt

'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'te/xt'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary2'|'text'
```

Which sets the field delimiter and the output field delimiter to the same value: `|`. Then makes a variable with the quote character `q="047"` (which will simplify the rest of the script) and then tests 3 things:

- The first field is exactly equal to `'ABC'`.
- The third field is either `'Y'` or `'N'`.
- The fourth field actually contains an `/`.

Then, do:

- Remove the first `/` inside the fourth field.
- Print the whole line.

Which is different than the grep command you posted in that grep tests ABC with a regex. If that is what you want, then replace the `$1 == q"ABC"q` with `$1 ~ "ABC"` or even just `~"ABC"` (which will find an ABC anywhere on the whole input line).

It also seems redundant to test for either `Y` or `N` if all the input lines have either one of those values. If so, you could remove the second test.

That could allow the awk command to be simplified to:

```
awk '($1~/ABC/)&&sub("/","",$4)' FS="|" OFS="|" test.txt
```

If you need to replace all the `/` in the fourth field, then you could change the function `sub` with `gsub`. Just note that some OS (even current ones) might carry [older `awk` implementations](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/awkcompat.html#os73) that might not support gsub.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split("|"); if @a.[0].match(/ ABC /) && @a.[2].match(/ <[YN]> /)  \
             { @a.[3].=trans("/" => ""); put @a.join("|") };' file
```

Similar to other answers, this treats the OP's file somewhat like a CSV file, with the caveat that there are no embedded delimiters or newlines. The file is read linewise using the `-ne` non-autoprinting command line flags. Each line is split on `|` bar and saved into an array, `@a`. If the first column (`@a.[0]`) matches `ABC` and the third column (`@a.[2]`) matches either `Y` or `N`, the line is sent on for further processing within the `{...}` block.  [Note: single quotes within each column are ignored].

Within the `{...}` block, the fourth column (`@a.[3]`) is `trans`lated such that "/" forward-slashes are deleted. Then the `@a` elements are `join`ed back together with `|` bar, and out`put`.

Sample Input:

```
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john/1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john/1'|'te/xt'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary/2'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'?'|'mary/2'|'text'
'DEF'|filler|'N'|'jane/3'|'text'
```

Sample Output:

```
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'te/xt'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary2'|'text'
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score -1):

`tr` is meant for this kind of stuff:

```
grep ABC test.txt | grep "$wordY|$wordN'[[:alpha:]]+/" | tr -d '/'
```

`tr`, short for "translate", allows you to change any occurrence of a character in a given set, by either removing it, or by replacing it by a character in the same location in another set.

The `-d` argument selects "delete character" mode, where the characters from the given set (here the set is just one character, "/") are removed from the input before being rewritten to the output.

For more information, see `man tr`.

Comment: Note that this suffers from a similar issue to the original user's code: it matches `ABC` as a substring _anywhere_, not specifically in the first field and possibly as part of a longer string. This also removes the slash from the last field, which the user did not want to do ("should not be removed for `'te/xt'`")